# fastest way to find an integer in a dataset

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, search, lookup

The interview question is more complicated, so i simplified it as

1. input data will be in a format of `A,B`
2. A is a number between 0 and 18446744073709551615(mysql bigint)
3. B is a random string
4. we will provide IO part

You should provide two functions in c/c++

1. set(unsigend long long A, char *B)
2. get(unsigend long long A)

data struct and algorithm is up to you.

Requirements

1. set should be O(1)
2. get should be O(1)

Put in mind that we might call set 100 million times

Any ideas? I did not give a good answer

my answer was incomplete:

```
typedef data {
    unsigned long long A;
    char *B;
    data *next;
}
```

set is just malloc a new data and append to the list

but failed in get part.

Comment: what was your answer ?

Comment: `O(1)` think hash.

Comment: If you know what a hash table is using a hash function, this is an easy answer.  `set()` would set the key value with `A` as key and `B` as Value, Get would `get()` value `B` using Key `A`...  Out of curiosity, can you state what company this is for?

Comment: Hash tables offer this behaviour: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/Hash_Tables

Comment: my answer is to use linked list to store the data

Comment: list insertion is bit costlier ..as well as to find (get)

Comment: A hash table would be an array of Structs (not linked list), with each struct having an optional next value (a linked list) to account for possible duplicates (i.e. collision).

Comment: Traversal required to get

Comment: Even the hash  a problem of rehasing when setting ..(if the bucket capacity is exceeded )

Comment: @Sato -- *data struct and algorithm is up to you* --  That is just secret code for "does this person know or ever heard of a hash table?".

Comment: `std::unordered_map<unsigned long long, std::string>` should do it.

Comment: Please clarify: C or C++ ? Because those are **different languages** and code would not look the same at all. You sample code suggest C...

Comment: A hash doesn't give `O(1)` worst-case complexity. It gives only `Θ(1)` average case complexity. The trie answer is right for `O(1)`, because the number of digits is constant.

Comment: Hmmm `set(unsigend long long A, char *B)`  --> perhaps the company needs a dictionary?  I'd expect .........`unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this in C this way. I think you will understand my idea from the code. (Note by [nos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126769/nos): this algorithm is known as [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node node;

struct node {
    node *nodes[0x10];
    char *text;
};

node *top;

void set(unsigned long long A, char *B)
{
    unsigned char n;
    node *way;

    way = top;

    for (;A>0;A>>=4)
    {
        n = A & 0xf;

        if (way->nodes[n] == NULL)
        {
            way->nodes[n] = malloc(sizeof(node));
            memset(way->nodes[n], 0, sizeof(node));
        }

        way = way->nodes[n];
    }

    if (way->text != NULL)
    {
        free(way->text);
    }

    way->text = strdup(B);
}

char *get(unsigned long long A)
{
    unsigned char n;
    node *way;

    way = top;

    for (; A>0 && way != NULL; A>>=4)
    {
        n = A & 0xf;
        way = way->nodes[n];
    }

    if (A == 0 && way != NULL)
    {
        return way->text;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    top = malloc(sizeof(node));
    memset(top,0,sizeof(node));

    set(1230294381243, "test1");
    set(12934839, "test2");
    set(1,"tezt");

    printf("%s", get(1230294381243));
    printf("%s", get(12934839));
    printf("%s", get(1));

//    todo: free memory
//    free_way(top); 

    return 0;
}
```

Max 16 iterations to find any `unsigned long long` key. This code is 100% working and was tested, except freeing memory from the `top` variable.

**UPDATE**. Declaring `node`s as an array (suggestion by [HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat)).

**UPDATE**. Increasing algorithm speed (suggestion by [Serge Rogatch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915854/serge-rogatch))

Comment: The `node`s being a single array would look slightly better.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks, you are right. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Note that what you have implemented is called a Trie.

Comment: Oh, I missed that, I thought the second piece of code is just a test. Then you should remove the old code, because it distracts. Also, division&modulo operations are slow: it's better to use 16 hexadecimal digits `0...F` and bit shifts and logical AND: `for (;A>0;A>>=4) { n = A & 0xf;` . Also `malloc() + strcpy()` can be replaced with `strdup()`.

Comment: The nodes array should be one larger than it currently is, ie 0x10 instead of 0xf

Comment: Simplification option: `if (way->text != NULL)
    {
        free(way->text);
    }` --> `free(way->text);`  `free(NULL)` is OK.

Comment: "This code is 100% working "?? IMO, a bug: `A=15` and `void set(unsigned long long A, char *B) { n = A & 0xf;     if (way->nodes[n] == NULL)` as `(way->nodes[15]`  is UB.

Comment: @SergeRogatch The optimizations [offered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993688/fastest-way-to-find-an-integer-in-a-dataset#comment78960704_45997856) are at best _maybe_.  `n = A & 0xf;` and `n = A % 16;` will certainly emit the same code.  If not, the compiler needs updating.  The `malloc() + strcpy()` v. `strdup()` bypasses allocation checking and potential superior performance with `memcpy()`.  As with optimizations that are liner, best to profile. It also appears vadim_hr updates per your suggestion were incorrectly used and thus loses its 100% test-ness and gained a bug you noted.

Comment: @chux ok thanks for help. this is my mistake. bug fixed

Comment: @chux, it was `A%10` earlier, so I suggested to change the base to 16.

Comment: Thanks, I see you changed the array size from 10 to 16, does the size matter? can I change it to 32 or 4, for example?

Comment: @Sato yes you can (power of 2 is acceptable: 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ...), but you must change `set()` and `get()` accordingly. for example for 32 you need change `>>=4` to `>>=5` and `A & 0xf` to `A & 0x1f`. I think you understand this.

Comment: @vadim_hr so big array size uses more memory but decreases lookup time, while small array size uses little memory but increase lookup time? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @Sato yes this is correct, more memory - faster speed. less memory - slower speed.

Answer (score 0):

As an interview question,  it is reasonable to consider the impacts of coding goals.

Consider

1. hash suggested by [@PaulMcKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993688/fastest-way-to-find-an-integer-in-a-dataset#comment78947284_45993688)
2. A Trie suggested by [@Serge Rogatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993688/fastest-way-to-find-an-integer-in-a-dataset#comment78960375_45993688) and answered by [@vadim_hr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45997856/2410359)
3. *Huge* arrays `char *even[18446744073709551615u/2+1]; char *odd[18446744073709551615u/2+1];`

The requirements "set should be O(1), get should be O(1)" puts aside the hash solution as it is not truly O(1).  Still a hash can have excellent *average* speed and resource rating.

Yet there was no memory efficiency requirement, nor memory limit, nor set size (other than an implied < 100 million).

A naive implementation of #3 (Arrays) would certainly exceed real memory budgets, yet it is O(1), in theory.  Still not a *real* candidate even though it meets the stated requirements and within memory limits (which are theoretically unbounded).

The issue with a Trie is its bottom leafs are often a wide array of `NULL` pointers - making this approach memory intensive.  Yet if the set count (unknown) is small this is not a concern.

---

> Put in mind that we might call set 100 million times

This point is not reflected in a trie implementation as that reminder is to **also consider over-all efficiency**.  A trie can be very memory inefficient with a high set count and slower, on average, than a dynamic hash - even with its O(1) get/set.

This is where the interview part comes in to not just provide a technical solution that meets the requirements, certainly a trie, but to presents its advantages (O(1) for get/set) and its short-comings (memory hog), average speed slow than a hash.  Thus to **insure your customer** (the interviewer in this case) is **apprised of other reasonable solutions** that may better meet the *overall* objectives.